# Correlation coefficient between two regressions

Tags: statistics, regression

Given two regression equations

$$y = 15 + 2.5x$$
$$x = 2 + 0,2y$$

How do I get the correlation coefficient between the two variables?

Comment: Hint: $2.5 \times 0.2=0.5 < 1$

Comment: You can also find $\bar x=10, \bar y=40$

Comment: The result is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ @Henry

Comment: Indeed it is.  I would have found it as $\sqrt{2.5 \times 0.2}$ (and in this case the positive square root)

Comment: @Henry, How did you manage to deduce that? I can't see

Comment: From [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) $\hat{\beta}_{X,Y} = r\frac{s_Y}{s_X}$ and $\hat{\beta}_{Y,X} = r \frac{s_X}{s_Y}$ so $\hat{\beta}_{X,Y} \hat{\beta}_{Y,X} = r^2$ and $r= \pm \sqrt{\hat{\beta}_{X,Y} \hat{\beta}_{Y,X}}$

Comment: Very good! Thanks @Henry